# Are hierarchical deterministic Keys secure even against their children?

Tags: deterministic-wallets

Say for example, you have 1 HD Key and are generating multiple children keys. Say a max of `2147483647` child keys.

Would it be possible to figure out the parent HD pub/priv keys if somebody were to get a large percentage of the child keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The computation from children from a parent is like a hash (and involves hashes). It doesn't matter how many children someone sees, they cannot compute the parent key. They cannot even tell which child keys come from the same parent.

The only thing that's possible, and perhaps surprising, is that given a parent xpub, and a privkey derived from it, you can compute the parent xprv.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was wondering. Okay will keep the child private keys secure too